# Using pause() to wait for child processes

Tags: c, sockets, signals

I am new to network programming, so I need an advice. I have a simple server, which will  serve up to 3 clients at the same time. When the 4th client arrives, it should wait until one of the current clients end service. Here is part of my code

```
    for(;;) {

      if(nchilds == 3) {
         /* server must wait until one of his children terminate */
         pause();
      }

      if((clientfd = accept(serverfd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &addr_len)) == -1) {
         perror("accept");
         continue;
      }

      if((pid = fork()) > 0){ // parent process
         nchilds++;

      }else if(pid == 0){ // child process

         /* for client process this is unnecessary socket, so close it */
         tcpsock_destroy(serverfd);

         if(!serve_client(clientfd)) {
            perror("serve_client");
            return 1;
         }

         /* close the connection with the client */
         tcpsock_destroy(clientfd);
         return 0;

      }else{
         perror("fork");
      }
   }
```

What I want to do is to serve up to 3 clients simultaneously. So I have a counter which counts number of active clients. And when the counter is 3 the server must wait. 
I want to use `pause()` in server process, and register to SIGCHLD, a signal handler which will do `nchilds--`. Is it safe and correct way of doing this, or there is a better solution? Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked out the `wait(2)` syscall?

Comment: @Andy, yes I used blocking version of wait, I putted `nchilds--` after wait(). But the problem with wait() is that if 2 clients will terminate at the same time, `nchilds` will be decremented just once.

Comment: use additional non blocking `waitpid()` calls if `nchilds < 3`; Then you can always set `nchilds` to the right value